# How to navigate from Flutter Page to Native Android Page

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

In this i am creating an app in which i successfully added the flutter module in existing android app by using these links https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app , https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/add-flutter-screen. Here the launch screen is native android and then i added a button to navigate to flutter screen. But my question is how do i navigate from flutter screen to native android screen. Here is the code of native android and dart code. **Note: I already added the flutter module dependencies in build.gradle and also added the code in settings.gradle, so i am not going to mention the code.**

> MainActivity.java

```
Button btn1;
        btn1=findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(FlutterActivity.createDefaultIntent(v.getContext())); //this navigate to flutter page
            }
        });
```

> Main.dart

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Demo'),),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: (){
              //Here how do i navigate to Native Android Screen ?
            },
            child: Text('Navigate to Android'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to navigate between flutter screen to native(android/ios) screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247602/how-to-navigate-between-flutter-screen-to-nativeandroid-ios-screens)

Comment: @Benjamin yes, i already seen this but could not find the code of navigate or move from flutter page to android page.

Comment: All you have to do is just navigate once the message is received.

Comment: @Benjamin In flutter to navigate to new screen we use this code `Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
  );` So using this code how to navigate or move to native android page?

Comment: You can't, because Flutter doesn't know those pages exist. Like in that answer, you have to send a message from Flutter to Android telling it to navigate and you have to change views once you recieve that message. The other option would be to re-create the screen in Flutter so that you can navigate using the `Navigator` class.

Comment: @Benjamin Could you please explain the recreate screen in flutter.

Comment: I'm just saying that you could recreate the screen that you have to navigate to in native Android in Flutter.

Comment: @Benjamin Regarding the sending a message from Flutter to Android could you provide me an example because the link which you have mentioned is not clear to understand.

Comment: I'm not a native Android developer so I don't know but just do some research and you'll find it.

Answer (score 2):

In Dart code, you should invoke a method through Platform Channel, to call a native function to navigate from the activity/view controller which hosts your Flutter pages, you can't directly navigate to a native vipageew from Dart code.

```
 // .dart file
 void _exitFlutter() {
    PlatformChannel.invokeMethod('navToNative');
 }

// .kt or .java file
MethodChannel(flutterEngine!!.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
        .setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
          run {
            when (call.method) {
              "navToNative" -> // start your activity here
              else -> result.notImplemented()
            }
          }
        }
```

You can check the detail here https://github.com/duytq94/demo-integrate-flutter